# jQuery: Closing child dialog window

Tags: jquery, dialog

I got a jquery dialog window with some tabs, dynamic data, etc. In it there´s a button, which calls another dialog. That dialog has two buttons for save and close...If I click on close, it does which is supposed to do. But if I click on save, the content is saved and dialog closed, but the parent dialog is closed also, which I don´t want. How is this usually solved? Code of child dialog is here:

```
$('<div id="popis" style="display:none">').dialog({
        title: 'Popis rizika',
        height:300,
        buttons:{
                'Uložit': function(){
                    $("#popisRizika").submit();
                    $(this).remove();
                },


    'Zrušit': function(){
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },                  
    },
    open: function(event, ui){
        $(this).load('rizika_popis.php?stupen='+<?echo $IdStStupen;?>+'&index='+i);
    },
    close: function(ev, ui){
            $(this).remove();
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because your are submiting the form `$("#popisRizika").submit();` when save is click.. and that makes wholepage to reload and thus resulting in closing of the parent dialog and the child too.. what you need here is posting a form through [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or $.get.. this will not reload the page and hence you can close the child dialog manually after success callback

something like this ,using **$.post** :

```
 'Uložit': function(){
                $.post(url,$("#popisRizika").serialize(),function(result){
                   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                })
            },
```